# undefined references in libpthread and libc

Tags: c++, linux, linker, g++, undefined-reference

I'm having trouble compiling some examples in a odbc sdk. After some time mingling with the library order, I somehow managed to get the number of undefined references to just a handful of them.

Sadly, I can't figure out how to get rid of the remaining ones. Here's the command that's failing:

```
g++ -Wall -z defs -m64 -DSIMBA -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -O0 -g -shared Common/TabbedUnicodeFileReader_Linux_x8664_debug.cpp.o Core/QSConnection_Linux_x8664_debug.cpp.o Core/QSDriver_Linux_x8664_debug.cpp.o Core/QSEnvironment_Linux_x8664_debug.cpp.o Core/QSStatement_Linux_x8664_debug.cpp.o DataEngine/QSDataEngine_Linux_x8664_debug.cpp.o DataEngine/QSMetadataHelper_Linux_x8664_debug.cpp.o DataEngine/QSTable_Linux_x8664_debug.cpp.o DataEngine/QSTableUtilities_Linux_x8664_debug.cpp.o DataEngine/QSTypeInfoMetadataSource_Linux_x8664_debug.cpp.o Common/QSTableMetadataFile_Unix_Linux_x8664_debug.cpp.o Common/QSUtilities_Unix_Linux_x8664_debug.cpp.o Main_Unix_Linux_x8664_debug.cpp.o    -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--no-allow-shlib-undefined -Wl,--whole-archive,/home/hector/Downloads/SimbaEngineSDK/9.0/DataAccessComponents//Lib/Linux_x8664/libSimbaDSI_debug.a,/home/hector/Downloads/SimbaEngineSDK/9.0/DataAccessComponents//Lib/Linux_x8664/libSimbaSupport_debug.a,/home/hector/Downloads/SimbaEngineSDK/9.0/DataAccessComponents//Lib/Linux_x8664/libAEProcessor_debug.a,/home/hector/Downloads/SimbaEngineSDK/9.0/DataAccessComponents//Lib/Linux_x8664/libCore_debug.a,/home/hector/Downloads/SimbaEngineSDK/9.0/DataAccessComponents//Lib/Linux_x8664/libDSIExt_debug.a,/home/hector/Downloads/SimbaEngineSDK/9.0/DataAccessComponents//Lib/Linux_x8664/libExecutor_debug.a,/home/hector/Downloads/SimbaEngineSDK/9.0/DataAccessComponents//Lib/Linux_x8664/libParser_debug.a,/home/hector/Downloads/SimbaEngineSDK/9.0/DataAccessComponents//Lib/Linux_x8664/libSimbaODBC_debug.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -Wl,--soname=../Bin/Linux_x8664/libQuickstart_debug.so -L/home/hector/Downloads/SimbaEngineSDK/9.0/DataAccessComponents//ThirdParty/icu/Linux_x8664/lib -licuuc_simba64 -licudata_simba64 -licui18n_simba64 -lpthread -lm -lc -ldl -Wl,--version-script=exports_Linux.map -o ../Bin/Linux_x8664/libQuickstart_debug.so
```

Edit: Missing symbols

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so: undefined reference to `_dl_rtld_di_serinfo@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to `_dl_allocate_tls_init@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to `__libc_stack_end@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to `_dl_get_tls_static_info@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to `__tls_get_addr@GLIBC_2.3'
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to `_dl_deallocate_tls@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to `_rtld_global@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: undefined reference to `_dl_argv@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: undefined reference to `__libc_enable_secure@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to `_dl_allocate_tls@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to `_rtld_global_ro@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to `_dl_make_stack_executable@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
```

Fixed:

Removing -Wl,--no-allow-shlib-undefined seemed to do the trick. The built shared library seems to work perfectly.

Comment: Post the error messages that you are getting.

Comment: Which symbols are missing? I can't see that in the post...

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue with a completely separate application. The following compile time flag worked for me:

-B/usr/lib/gold-ld/

which i found at:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/binutils/+bug/885927

I'm using gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1 I was trying to compile with lto.

Comment: Thanks! Using `gold-ld` worked out for me as well. For those using CMAKE: `set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS -fuse-ld=gold)`

Answer (score 4):

You do a very common newbie mistake. you place the libraries to link with in the middle or the beginning of the command line. The linker GCC uses needs dependencies in *reverse* order. That means if you have an source/object file S using a function in library L, the file A has to be before the library L on the command line.

In short, put the libraries (`-lm -lc -ldl`) last on the command line instead.

Comment: @HectorIzquierdo You have some libraries in two places. If the linker has already loaded a library it won't load it again, and then lookup will fail. Remove all libraries before the source/object files, and keep them at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Joachim. Sadly I still get the same undefined reference errors

Answer (score 2):

If linker fails to resolve all referenced symbols then this can be a result of wrong order of provided libraries. If you are not sure what is the correct order then put archives in "--start-group archives --end-group" which according to ld manual will force linker to search the specified archives repeatedly until no new undefined references are created. But pay attention to a performance cost.

Answer (score 0):

The OP mentioned "Removing `-Wl,--no-allow-shlib-undefined`" helped.
In my case I had to add the opposite:
`-Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined`

(Everything was working fine with an older version of GCC)